# How can I store a function pointer in a structure?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have declared `typedef void (*DoRunTimeChecks)();`

How do I store that as a field in a struct? How do I assign it? How do I call the fn()?

Comment: Note that, in C, `void fn()` and `void fn(void)` are not synonymous.

Comment: +1 thanks. I already fell into that

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just put it in like you would any other field:

```
struct example {
   int x;
   DoRunTimeChecks y;
};

void Function(void)
{
}

struct example anExample = { 12, Function };
```

To assign to the field:

```
anExample.y = Function;
```

To call the function:

```
anExample.y();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*DoRunTimeChecks)();

struct func_struct {
    DoRunTimeChecks func;
};

void function()
{
    puts("hello");
}

int main()
{
    struct func_struct func_struct;
    func_struct.func = function;
    func_struct.func();
    return 0;
}
```